# Schedule for Batch

Tags: apex, batch, class, schedulebatch, execute-anonymous

I made a Batch class and Schedule to call that class. However, I am not able to test in Execute Anonymous Window.

***schedule***

```
global class UpdateUserDataSchedule implements Schedulable {
     global void execute (SchedulableContext sc) {
         UpdateUserDataBatch u = new UpdateUserDataBatch ();
         database.executebatch ((u), 5);
        
     }
}
```

***Batch***

```
global void execute (Database.BatchableContext BC, List <User> scope) {
// ...
}
```

**Execute Anonymous Window:**

```
UpdateUserDataShedule.execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List <User> scope);
```

**Error:
Line: 1, Column: 30
Unexpected token '('.**

Answer (score 1):

This isn't valid Apex and is not how you invoke a batch class:

```
UpdateUserDataShedule.execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List <User> scope);
```

To run a batch class, create an instance of the batch and call `Database.executeBatch()`, just like you do in your `Schedulable` class:

```
     UpdateUserDataBatch u = new UpdateUserDataBatch ();
     Database.executeBatch (u, 5);
```

To directly call the `execute()` method, you would need to instantiate a `Database.BatchableContext` object (or simply pass `null` if, like most batch classes, you don't use it) and provide a `List<User>`. However, one typically does not call `execute()` directly, outside of some unit testing scenarios.

If you wanted to execute your scheduler class synchronously (i.e., without actually scheduling it), you'd have to create a new instance and call its `execute()` method:

```
new UpdateUserDataSchedule().execute(null);
```

As a side note, unless you are building a managed package and deliberately are exposing these classes outside that package, none of these items should be `global`.

Comment: Thanks
it worked using: new UpdateUserDataSchedule().execute(null);

Answer (score 0):

The schedulable class should have the form you have described.

The basic content of the **batch** class should be of the form:

```
global without sharing class BatchProcessName implements Database.Batchable<SObject>
{

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc)
    {
        string qry = 'SELECT id FROM somewhere';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(qry);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, list<SObject> listVariable)
    {
        //clever code goes here using listVariable
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc)
    {
        // execute any post-processing operations
    }

}
```

Then to call it from your dev console's execute anonymous window:

```
BatchProcessName b = new BatchProcessName();
database.executeBatch(b,1);
```

It's not clear from your example whether the batch is declared properly; with "global" access modifiers.

Hope that helps.

Comment: `global` access is neither required nor recommended for a batch class _unless_ it is part of a managed package and intended to be accessible outside that package.

Comment: There's also no reason to implement the `Database.Stateful` marker interface if you have no instance variables.

Comment: David, take both your points entirely. My code was extracted from a managed package and wasn't entirely cleaned up. Though the original question did indicate global modifiers.